# How to record a flash movie from a live cam on the Internet?

Tags: software-rec, camera, recording

I am watching some webcams live from the Internet, showing some big cities around the world. I'd like to record some to show to my friends at home.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest soultion that comes into my mind is recording the part of the screen itself using a Screencasting software like Kazam. Or Record my desktop or similar.

You can install Kazam in debian based distros by `sudo apt-get install kazam`.

[image]

As you can see it has an **Area selection option**. So, you can just select the area of the window and record it.